# How to use Ricci identity to prove exchange of laplacian beltrami operator and derivative with Levi-Civita tensor involved in 2D

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to prove the following equation using Ricci identity for the 2D manifold:
$$\nabla^{2}(\mathbf{\epsilon}\cdot\nabla \Phi)-\mathbf{\epsilon}\cdot\nabla (\nabla^{2}\Phi) = K\mathbf{\epsilon}\cdot\nabla\Phi,$$
where $\Phi$ is a scalar function, $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ is 2D Levi-Civita tensor, $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of the 2D manifold.
My attempt:
I figured out how to prove this one:
$$\nabla^{2}(\nabla\Phi)-\nabla(\nabla^{2}\Phi)=K\nabla\Phi.$$
But with a $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ involved, I do not know how to prove it. Can someone help, thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? I think you just need to contract with $\epsilon$.